# How can I get my django-ckeditor installation to recognize?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have been following the instructions at https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor, and wiped the database to get the RichTextField() to register. My models.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import settings
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    body = RichTextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = "URL")
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    script = models.TextField(blank = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Page "' + self.title + '" at ' + self.location
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
```

However, ckeditor isn't showing up for the "body" field, and a look at the page source for the admin Page editor betrays no reference to ckeditor.

The JavaScript inclusions are:

```
<title>Add page | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
```

What can/should I do so that the "body" field of a "Page" has a CKeditor for its widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but it hasn't been answered and it may help others...

Below are the steps I follow when using Ckeditor on django.

1.Add 'ckeditor' to installed apps on settings.py

2.Add ckeditor config variables in settings.py. (upload location and tools)

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = MEDIA_ROOT
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "ckeditor/")

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {

    'default': {
        'toolbar': [
            ['Undo', 'Redo',
             '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',
             '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor',
             '-', 'Format',
             '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt',
             '-', 'Maximize',
             '-', 'Language',
            ],
        ],
        'height': '100%',
        'width': '100%',
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
    'full': {
        'toolbar': [
            ['Undo', 'Redo',
             '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList',
             '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
             '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock',
             '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor',
             '-', 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks',  #'Image' ,
             '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText',
            ],
            ['-', 'SpecialChar',
             '-', 'Source',
            ],
            [
                '-', 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'
            ],
            [
                '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'
            ]
        ],
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '600px',
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
    'disable': {
        'toolbar': [],
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '600px',
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
}
```

3.Add ckeditor to the models

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Article(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField(default="")
```

4.Finally, the magic happens when you add ckeditor widget in a form:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
from apps.articles.models import Article


class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(config_name='full'), label=_('Content'))

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

Of course, don't forget

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

to get all static data to your static dir, and

```
python manage.py makemigrations model_name
python manage.py migrate model_name
```

to create the databases fields.

One more thing! Add this to the page head when the form is used in order to load the necessary scripts for ckeditor to work

```
{{ form_name.media }}
```

;-)